# Circular Dependency Issue in My Visitor Design Pattern

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, circular-reference, visitor-pattern

I am trying to implement the visitor design pattern to build a tree of expressions for an interpreter. I am declaring everything in a header file and run into an issue where I need to define visitor before everything else but that's impossible because my Expr class needs visitor defined before it but then *thats* impossible because the other classes need Expr defined before them and I'm just unsure what to do.

```
#include "Token.h"

template <typename R>
class Visitor {
        virtual R visitBinaryExpr(Binary expr);
};

class Expr {
public:
template<typename R>
    R accept(Visitor<R> visitor);
};

class Binary : public Expr {
public:
    Binary(Expr left, Token oper, Expr right) : left(left), oper(oper), right(right)    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    T accept(T visitor) {
        return visitor.visitBinaryExpr(this);
    }

    const Expr left;
    const Token oper;
    const Expr right;
};
```

Gives syntax error: identifier 'Binary' on line 5

Heres a small example of the code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Comment: you need forward declaration, pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: `template<typename T> T accept(T visitor)` is suspicious, return value mismatch, and taking visitor by reference to avoid the slicing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with cyclic references has been solved by a visitor pattern shown by Andrei Alexandrescu in his book: " Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied"

He calls the pattern: "Acyclic Visitor"

To be honest. You program looks very much like his example. But anyway. To make it happen, you could do slight modifications.

I also implemented such a generic visitor [here](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/include/visitor.hpp).

Code:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Visitor part

    // You need to derive a Visitor class from VisitorBase. That is mandatory
    class VisitorBase
    {
        public:
            VisitorBase(void) {}
            virtual ~VisitorBase(void) {}
    };


    // Additionally you need to derive your visitor class from this class
    // and as many times as you want to visit specific classes that you must define
    // as template parameters.
    //
    // So a typical visitor class definition looks like
    //
    // class AVisitorForSomeOtherTypes :    public VisitorBase
    //                                      public Visitor<VisitibleType1>,
    //                                      public Visitor<VisitibleType2>,
    //                                      public Visitor<VisitibleTypex>
    //
    // With such a Visitor you can visit the classes specified in the template parameters
    //
    template <class T>
    class Visitor
    {
        public:
            Visitor(void) {}
            virtual ~Visitor(void) {}
            
            virtual void visit(T&) = 0;
    };


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2. Visitable part

    class VisitableBase
    {
        public:
            VisitableBase(void) {}
            virtual ~VisitableBase() {}
            // Will be overridden by macro
            // If somebody forgets to insert the macro, we will do nothing
            virtual void acceptAGuestVisitor(VisitorBase&) { };
        protected:
        
            // Because the DEFINE_VISITABLE macro will be used to finally call this function
            // Type T, set to "this" of the class where the macro was defined, T will be
            // of the type of the class where the macro was defined
            // This is just a redirector. And it avoids circular forward declarations
            // Hence "Acyclic"
            
            template <class TypeOfClassThatWillBeVisited>
            static void acceptDecoupled(TypeOfClassThatWillBeVisited& visited, VisitorBase* guestVisitorWhoWillVisitSomeOtherClass)
            {
                // Apply the Acyclic Visitor
                // Since Visitor classes are always derived from VisitorBase
                // and specific Visitor <templated> classes, the dynamic cast will 
                // work, if the guest, is also in the list of Base Classes from which 
                // the visitor is derived
                //
                // The visit function will not be called for unknown Visitors
                // in the example above, not for a "VisitibleTypekkk"
                
                if (Visitor<TypeOfClassThatWillBeVisited>* visitorGuest =   dynamic_cast<Visitor< TypeOfClassThatWillBeVisited>*>(guestVisitorWhoWillVisitSomeOtherClass))
                {
                    // Call the Visitors visit function (if existing)
                    visitorGuest->visit(visited);
                }
                return;
            }
    };


// This Macro hast to be defined in the class that shall be visited.
// So, in the visitable class.
// It will define the accept function which is typical for the visitor pattern.
// Accept will then call the "static acceptDecoupled" function, which 
// calls the visit function with "*this" (of the class where the macro was defined)
// as parameter.
#define DEFINE_VISITABLE() virtual void acceptAGuestVisitor(VisitorBase* guestVisitorWhoWillVisitSomeOtherClass) { acceptDecoupled(*this, guestVisitorWhoWillVisitSomeOtherClass); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that was fast! Yup, forward declaration was what I needed. I was confusing another issue caused by not defining my methods as some sort of problem with my use of forward declaration. My code now looks like,

```
#include "Token.h"

class Binary;
class Grouping;
class LiteralExpression;
class Unary;

template <typename R>
class Visitor {
    virtual R visitBinaryExpr(Binary expr) { R temp; return temp; };
};

class Expr {
public:
    template<typename R>
    R accept(Visitor<R> visitor) { R temp; return temp; };
};

class Binary : public Expr {
public:
    Binary(Expr left, Token oper, Expr right) : left(left), oper(oper), right(right)    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    T accept(T visitor) {
        return visitor.visitBinaryExpr(this);
    }

    const Expr left;
    const Token oper;
    const Expr right;
};
```

Though, now I am a bit worried as to whether the accept method will work or if it will just call my temp one from the base Expr class. Oh well, that's a question for another time. Thanks for the help!